# Recursively mapping props to React children in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recursion, typing

I'm creating a React bindings layer to create a simple connection between a UI library and an SDK.

To do this I'm recursively mapping properties from a parent component to every child within the node, for example:

```
<Bookies.UserBookieList>
  <BookieBarItem />
</Bookies.UserBookieList>
```

where `Bookies.UserBookieList` would apply a set of props/methods to it's child and that child's children etc.

The recursive map function is as follows:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, ReactElement } from 'react';

export default function recursivelyMapChildren<AddedProperties>(
  children: ReactElement<PropsWithChildren<AddedProperties>>[],
  addedProperties: AddedProperties
): any {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!child.props.children) {
      return React.cloneElement<PropsWithChildren<AddedProperties>>(child, addedProperties);
    }
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement<PropsWithChildren<AddedProperties>>(
        child,
        addedProperties,
        ...recursivelyMapChildren<PropsWithChildren<AddedProperties>>(
          child.props.children as ReactElement<PropsWithChildren<AddedProperties>>[],
          addedProperties
        )
      );
    }
    return child;
  });
}
```

And this is how `Bookies.UserBookieList` is using it:

```
interface UserBookieListChildProps {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  bookiePosition: number;
  index: number;
  isActive: boolean;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  onBookieSelect: (bookie: any, bookiePosition: number) => void;
}

class UserBookieList extends PureComponent<UserBookieListProps> {
  public handleBookieSelect = (bookie: any, bookiePosition: number) => {
    this.props.setClientBookie(bookie);

    trackEvent(TRACKING_EVENTS.USER_BOOKIE_SELECT, {
      betBookie: bookie,
      clickPosition: bookiePosition
    });
  };

  public render(): ReactElement<UserBookieListChildProps>[] {
    const { bookie: { code }, children, userBookies } = this.props;
    return userBookies.map((bookie: any, index: number) =>
      recursiveMap<UserBookieListChildProps>(children, {
        ...bookie,
        key: index,
        bookiePosition: index + 1,
        index,
        isActive: bookie.code === code,
        onBookieSelect: this.handleBookieSelect
      }).shift()
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error in my editor and during compilation because the child component isn't aware that the parent is providing the required props.

`TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<BookieBarItemProps>': code, index, isActive, loggedIn, and 2 more.`

I thought that providing the `UserBookieListChildProps` interface to `recursiveMap` and passing that to `React.cloneElement` as the element props typing would do the trick, but it doesn't...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try using react context to propagate the props.